# Eyes following cursor JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, animation, adobe

I made a scene in Adobe animate following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ma6HNRP2aU where the eyes follow the mouse cursor around. I changed the JS to add a third eye because my scene involves a three eyed monster. There is a syntax error which is stopping the scene from animating in Adobe Animate, but I'm not a coder and don't know what it is. The scene publishes fine without the code. Maybe you guys can spot the error? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
stage.addEventListener("mouseMove", arjun); 
function arjun(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    var var1 = mouseY - eyeR.y; 
    var var2 = mouseX - eyeR.x; 
    var radiusR = Math.atan2(var1,var2); 
    var degreeR = radiusR / (Math.PI / 180); 
    eyeR.rotation = degreeR; 

    var var3 = mouseY - eyeL.y; 
    var var4 = mouseX - eyeL.x; 
    var radiusR1 = Math.atan2(var3,var4); 
    var degreeR1 = radiusR1 / (Math.PI / 180); 
    eyeL.rotation = degreeR1;

    var var5 = mouseY - eyeT.y; 
    var var6 = mouseX - eyeT.x; 
    var radiusR2 = Math.atan2(var5,var6); 
    var degreeR2 = radiusR2 / (Math.PI / 180); 
    eyeT.rotation = degreeR2;
}
```

Comment: There is no *syntax error* in the actionscript (nothing to do with javascript) code you posted

Comment: Well, thank you for taking a look. Somehow the code is stopping the scene from publishing correctly. Do you have any idea what the issue might be? The scene publishes fine without the code, but is not functional obviously.

Comment: possibly `eyeT` hasn't been declared/defined/initiated properly (been years since I touched actionscript, so not sure the correct terminology in this case)